# Populate a sql table with duplicate data except for one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a sql table :

Levels

```
LevelId Min Product
1       x    1
2       y    1
3       z    1
4       a    1
```

I need to duplicate the same data into the database by changing only the product Id from 1 2,3.... 40

example

```
 LevelId Min Product
    1       x    2
    2       y    2
    3       z    2
    4       a    2
```

I could do something like

`INSERT INTO dbo.Levels SELECT top 4 * fROM  dbo.Levels` 
but that would just copy paste the data.
Is there a way I can copy the data and paste it changing only the Product value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're most of the way there - you just need to take one more logical step:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Levels (LevelID, Min, Product)
    SELECT LevelID, Min, 2 FROM dbo.Levels WHERE Product = 1
```

...will duplicate your rows with a different product ID.

Also consider that `WHERE Product = 1` is going to be more reliable than `TOP 4`. Once you have more than four rows in the table, you will not be able to guarantee that `TOP 4` will return the same four rows unless you also add an `ORDER BY` to the select, however `WHERE Product = ...` will always return the same rows, and will continue to work even if you add an extra row with a product ID of 1 (where as you'd have to consider changing `TOP 4` to `TOP 5`, and so on if extra rows are added).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the product id's and then load them in:

```
with cte as (
      select 2 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from cte
      where n < 40
     )
INSERT INTO dbo.Levels(`min`, product)
    SELECT `min`, cte.n as product
    fROM dbo.Levels l cross join
         cte
    where l.productId = 1;
```

This assumes that the `LevelId` is an identity column, that auto-increments on insert.  If not:

```
with cte as (
      select 2 as n
      union all
      select n + 1
      from cte
      where n < 40
     )
INSERT INTO dbo.Levels(levelid, `min`, product)
    SELECT l.levelid+(cte.n-1)*4, `min`, cte.n as product
    fROM dbo.Levels l cross join
         cte
    where l.productId = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Levels (LevelId, Min, Product)
SELECT TOP 4
    LevelId,
    Min,
    2
FROM dbo.Levels
```

You can include expressions in the `SELECT` statement, either hard-coded values or something like `Product + 1` or anything else.

I expect you probably wouldn't want to insert the LevelId though, but left that there to match your sample. If you don't want that just remove it from the `INSERT` and `SELECT` sections.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CROSS JOIN` against a numbers table, for example.

```
WITH
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS O), -- 2 rows
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS C FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B), -- 4 rows
  Nums AS(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N FROM L1)
SELECT
  lvl.[LevelID],
  lvl.[Min],
  num.[N]
FROM dbo.[Levels] lvl
CROSS JOIN Nums num
```

This would duplicate 4 times.